# Infer the Type of Component Props based on the Type of an Attribute

Tags: typescript

I have a component that takes in a `labels` attribute.

```
<Component
  defaultValue={FURNITURE.BED}
  labels={[
    {
      value: FURNITURE.BED,
      text: 'Bed',
    },
    {
      value: FURNITURE.COUCH,
      text: 'Couch',
    },
    {
      value: FURNITURE.CHAIR,
      text: 'Chair',
    },
  ]}
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  ...otherAttributes
/>
```

Where

```
export enum FURNITURE {
  BED = 'bed',
  COUCH = 'couch',
  CHAIR = 'chair'
}

type FurnitureOptions = `${FURNITURE}` // FURNITURE.BED | FURNITURE.COUCH | FURNITURE.CHAIR

const onSubmit = (value: FurnitureOptions} => processFurniture(value)
```

The problem is that the `value` prop in my `Component` is set as a string. In order to be passed into the function without any typing or lint issues (like type assertions), I'd like `Component` to infer the type based on the labels' values. In this case, `FurnitureOptions`.

My component is structured as

```
interface ILabel {
  readonly label: string;
  readonly value: string | number;
}

interface IComponentProps {
  readonly labels: ILabel[];
  readonly defaultValue: string | number | null;
  readonly onSubmit: (value: ILabel) => void;
  ...otherAttributes

const Component = ({
  labels, default, onSubmit, ...otherAttributes
}: IComponentProps => { ...function code }
```

Again, I'd like `string | number` to be replaced with any type parameter, like `FurnitureOptions`.

One solution is to create a type parameter `T` and manually call the component with `<Component<FurnitureOptions> ... />` but this is messy, against code standards, and I'd rather like to infer it automatically.

I know you can extract the possible values as so

```
type PossibleValues = Extract<typeof labels[number], { readonly [v in 'value']: unknown }>['value'] // FURNITURE.BED | FURNITURE.COUCH | FURNITURE.CHAIR
```

But I can't pass this in the `Component` parameters, otherwise I get a circular error

```
'labels' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer. ts(7022)
```

What ways are there for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need generics here.

Let's start with a generic type for your label:

```
interface ILabel<T extends string | number> {
  readonly label: string;
  readonly value: T;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
type ILabelTest = ILabel<FURNITURE>
```

And get a type that means your labels may only have value types that you pass in.

---

Then you need generic props.

```
interface IComponentProps<T extends string | number> {
  readonly labels: ILabel<T>[];
  readonly defaultValue: T | null;
  readonly onSubmit: (value: ILabel<T>) => void;
}
```

Now props can accept a generic type that is passed to the `labels`, as well as the `onSubmit` parameter.

---

Lastly, make your component generic so that you can provide that generic type to your props.

```
const Component = <T extends string | number>({
  labels,
  defaultValue,
  onSubmit,
}: IComponentProps<T>) => {
  //...
  return <></>
}
```

---

Now your code works as you expect:

```
const furnitureTest = <Component
  defaultValue={FURNITURE.BED}
  labels={[
    {
      value: FURNITURE.BED,
      label: 'Bed',
    },
    {
      value: FURNITURE.COUCH,
      label: 'Couch',
    },
    {
      value: FURNITURE.CHAIR,
      label: 'Chair',
    },
  ]}
  onSubmit={(item) => {
    console.log(item.value) // item.value is type: FURNITURE
  }}
/>
```

And it would even work with other label values:

```
const letterTest = <Component
  defaultValue="a"
  labels={[
    { label: 'A', value: 'a' },
    { label: 'B', value: 'b' },
  ]}
  onSubmit={item => item.value} // item.value is type: 'a' | 'b'
/>
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOJAOwFc8AxAVQQDkBJAFQ4CicAN6k4cAEICAInAC8BAEZIAJvgA0YuAGEA8m20AJeQTQRGaABYatRgILcEJ-FZTAoZAL7lg9GEihMdCQ4bgAZFGUAGwAeXjpKf3oVAGc4FJgoXwBzOAAfOCYQZSgAPhEtIhQVCHoogE84KMikKIAudMycgG5K1Bq6xoA3FCjGJA7eXu9SGHqwEPCWqN4kDJMl6Jj2Lj5BUp8-AKC0Re1cSHoGGAAFHDAUuISk1M6s+lyCopLy0XEqgYNJrLFIdTatOKlADaAF1ev9+rUgSokEFGFEYAA1UbjSb5QroqLwuAApGNWoAZUYihAwBgHQAFCMxhNQhEtrxSgBKeTlIYQYAqabkMz0dbncC1a4mJ5UF5pDLvT4E4oBUoMv7A6IpTTiFFojHYlm6uCU6m0mCaTxgiWXa53CAPSE8uS-LQAendADofX0YIwoPQ4DFSjF3QcZqL1pgA-Q6QGkKt1goYrapX4tPqUOisTikHJhDsePwEAIvVJpN5xM1tQWoVpxJrxOJmbi4EW9qXyzITc2ta0OvgJKobH3PL2Kn2W3mOh2S2W9AZDBPq8tB+cLNYJ+OG5Op63WXPBF77I4V-32gRtJY3B5tyaYVXTfQqTS6QWGXSkCAXW6+1GICiJAvSiCBsk-fwQC9A8eU9OAvygg94LSOYFlnDhi0EXc4KnXDmwAPQAfi0TxvHDchSCjeAgJgfwoCTeAUzTK4Mz1VFs0NPM5AAIhQbitBrVoUjrXdhAvQc7A0OAD0HFB8DgHc+zEwTLyHKSZKUeTFLgR8tDNN8YALBDeXgyDoLzJ8cLw6y+yI0hwyAA)

Comment: Thank you, but there's just one issue. There seems to be an order that Typescript infers the typing. For some reason, it looks at `onSubmit` first then `defaultValue`. For example, if I comment out `onSubmit`, then I get a typing error that says

`Type '"couch"' is not assignable to type '"bed"'.`

Because it thinks the type is `bed` from the `defaultValue`. How can I tell typescript to depth search to `labels` to get the type?

Comment: Scratch the previous statement. I've determined the actual cause, and my previous post redacted info that was important. So the problem is that I tried mixing labels of different types. For example, mixing `'a'` with `2` or `FURNITURE.BED`. Enums are accepted because they can only be number or string literals, and this is the only way to mix strings and numbers. In addition, you can't mix different enums, like `FURNITURE.BED` and `ANOTHER_ENUM.EXAMPLE`. May need to open another ticket for this.